# How do I send a FPDF doc using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, fpdf

I would like to merge or link the FPDF and PHPMailer code so that a document is generated and sent by email.  I do not want to save the file.  I am unable to find a solution.  Below is the working code for FPDF and also for PHPMailer.  Unable to merge the two together.

FPDF website says to do this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
...
$doc = $pdf->Output('', 'S');
$mail->AddStringAttachment($doc, 'doc.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
$mail->Send();
```

FPDF code:

```
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$fpdf = new FPDF();
$text="test";

$fpdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$fpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);

define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');

$fpdf->AddFont('Verdana', '','verdana.php'); // Standard Arial

$fpdf->addPage('L');

$fpdf->Image('images/certificate.jpg', 0, 0, 297, 210);

$fpdf->SetFont('Verdana', '');
$fpdf->SetFontSize(28);
$fpdf->SetTextColor(32, 56, 100); 
$fpdf->SetXY(108, 52); //
$fpdf->Cell(80, 6, $text, 0,0, 'C'); 

$fpdf->Output('Filename.pdf', 'i');
```

PHPMailer code:

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'gator3095';                      // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                              // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                   // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                      // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->From = 'test@hotmail.com.com';
$mail->FromName = 'John Doe';
$mail->AddAddress('recipient@hotmail.com', '');  // Add a recipient
$mail->IsHTML(true);                             // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->Body    = 'message body';
$mail->AltBody = 'messge body';
$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/test.php", "test.php");  

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$fpdf->Output('Filename.pdf', 'i');` by `$fpdf->Output('Filename.pdf', 'S');` to save your PDF on the harddrive instead of sending it directly to the browser (as explained in [the doc](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)).

Then call your FPDF code to generate the PDF file in the begining or before your PHPmailer.php code, replace `$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/test.php", "test.php");` by `$mail->AddAttachment("[...the exact place where your file is..]/Filename.pdf", "Filename.pdf");`

And finally, before your last echo, add `unlink('Filename.pdf');` to delete the temporary PDF file you've just sended.